# How to make responsive background-images that come from a CMS?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, media-queries

When developing a website I often use background images for banners. When this website is in a CMS, the images paths come from the database (user uploaded). So I ended up using a `style="background-image:url(myImageFromDB.jpg)"`

However, this becomes an issue when I want to replace this image with smaller versions of the same image.

A lot of tutorials/guides out there, assume that you already know the path to this image, so you can just use @media queries to easily replace them. But if the path is dynamic, then I can't use media queries (unless they are dynamically written in the head of the document).

So how are people dealing with this issue?

1. Not using background-images? (using  instead?)
2. Dynamically writing media queries at the head of the document?
3. Using JS to dynamically load the correct images?
4. Resizing images dynamically on the server?

My downsides of each method:
1. Downside, can't use some good options such as background-size:cover
2. Need to write server side script figure out what image to load
3. Probably the best option, but need to wait for the JS to load first
4. I have tried this, but without much success.

Comment: Another one to add to your list: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/.
This is a recent spec so there's not alot of browser support yet. There are also some good JS libraries for handling this. It really depends what you want to support.

Comment: I prefer the JS option and use a homespun srcset lib for bg images. It's easy to create a fallback, the images are async, and it can be set up to be loaded either immediately or with something like waypoints which is a plus for performance.

Comment: @SimonGooder I read that article before. Unfortunately is not addressing background-images just img tags.

Answer (score 0):

one thing you can do..
You can assign its width using view port width like *width:90vw;*.
1 vw=1/100 of total view.
so you need not change the image for small screen.
you can just simply add this in your media query and default css also.
*width:90vw;*..
you can change width as your requirement.
so it will act dynamically.
not need to change the image.
hope it works.

Comment: can you give me an example? banner images are really big (usually). It wouldn't be good to just resize the images with css because you would be forcing the user to download a big file size, for a small view area.

Comment: Yes you are right. I would not be good to resize the images if the the image size is too big.